# Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 7 (AWS) to Hadoop node

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop, oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to create a proof of concept showing that it is possible for a company to migrate their data from their oracle 12c DB to a hadoop system..

To do this I have started a Oracle Linux 7 instance on AWS. I am planning to install Oracle 12c on it.. after that I have to create dummy tables and send them to Hadoop..

can this be done? From my initial research I can see that Sqoop and Oracle GoldenGate can do that.. also if this goes live i would have to transfer billions of records from oracle 12c to HDFS..

Any help or advice is much much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use sqoop for transform your oracle data to hive. You can read this for more [info](https://weidongzhou.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/import-data-to-hive-from-oracle-database/)

Comment: How easy is it to connect oracle DB instance on AWS to the Hadoop system provided by Cloudera?

Comment: If you are BDA admin, it will be easy. Do you consider odi with hive ikm?

Comment: @jedijs-- I am actually looking into ODI.. i dont understand how it is different to golden gate from oracle.. to me it makes the most sense to use ODI..

Comment: @BobC I didnt get your comment.. which code are you talking about?

Comment: I was wondering about triggers, stored procedures, functions, packages etc. Basically all of the processing that you do in the database?

Comment: @BobC Only data

Comment: Thanks guys.. I managed to get a trial license of IBM biginsights which connected everything already..  :)